# Files put in other Macs' Drop Boxes don't appear

Tags: macos, file-sharing

One MacBook Pro will see other Macs' Public Folders, including their Drop Boxes, and will allow me to drop files into them, shows the copy dialog, takes a reasonable amount of time, and... doesn't actually transfer the files. I've tested with two different destination computers. Any ideas?